# ArcGIS Server - Feature Access from view

Tags: arcgis-server

I want to create a Feature Access Service using an Oracle View as DataSource.

In ArcMAP I can add the layer without problems, but when I try to publish the service, I get a "00134: Layer's data source is not supported" error.

Any ideas why?

I am using ArcGIS Desktop and Server, both version 10.3, and Oracle 12c

Comment: What server license do you have? (GIS Server Advanced, GIS Server Standard, GIS Server Basic)

Comment: ArcGIS for Server Basic Enterprise Up to Four Cores (Version 10.3.1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to ESRI's Server Functionality Matrix, web-based editing isn't capable with a basic licence. A Feature Access service offers editing capability.

http://www.esri.com/software/arcgis/arcgisserver/~/media/Files/Pdfs/library/brochures/pdfs/arcgis-server-functionality-matrix.pdf

[image]

Comment: I don't need editing capabilities, I should be able to select only the "query" part of the Feature Access

Comment: You should deselect Feature Access from the capabilities tab in Service Editor. A basic service published in ArcMap will include Query functionality. 
These instructions outline the different capabilities available in a Map Service: 
[setting-map-service-properties](https://enterprise.arcgis.com/en/server/latest/publish-services/windows/setting-map-service-properties.htm)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by others, Feature Access is used for editing. Your data source is a view, not a table. Views behave similarly to tables in terms of querying, but they don't usually store data on their own and thus are not editable.